# The background of MatDialog is showing a gray board in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Once I click the avatar button then I want a MatDialog to be launch
The MatDialog is opening but the background of it shows a gray board, not showing the background component.

**component.ts**

onAvatarClicked(): void {
this.uploadImgDialog.open(ImageCropperComponent, {
width: '350px',
panelClass: 'full-panel',
});
}

**imagecroppercomponent.html**

close
        Upload Image...
    
    
        
            Select File
            Upload

**showing image**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [backdropClass](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig), and modify the style of the dialog overlay in your global styles

for example your config

```
onAvatarClicked(): void { 
this.uploadImgDialog.open(ImageCropperComponent, { 
     width: '350px', 
     //Also make sure this line below isn't forcing some styles that are causing the issue you have
    panelClass: 'full-panel',
    // Add the line below
    backdropClass: 'custom-backdrop'
 }); }
```

in your global style

```
.custom-backdrop {
background-color: gray;
opacity: .2 !important;
}
```